# Is there a way of removing my votes from comments?

Tags: support, moderators, comments

Mistakenly, i have upvoted a comment recently. My issue is that i want to remove my upvote from it. But i am not being able to do so.

My question is, if i am not allowed to do that by myself, are there any moderators who has the privilege to do it for me? And, is the un-upvoting allowed?

Are the moderators of our site capable of doing the reversal? Or do i need contact a community Mod who has special powers?

Comment: A comment can be un-upvoted within 60 seconds. Either un-upvoted or timed-out, the un-upvote or upvote will remain forever then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129032/357396) mother meta post

1.You can unupvote a comment within one minute and should not navigate away.
2.Once you un-upvote a comment you can not upvote it again.

Moderators cannot reverse the score of a comment or an answer because it is a type of opinion or a voice of a user. They can edit or delete a comment.

Contacting a community manager for a comment upvote is not at all suggested because it is just a comment. It is likely that they will ignore this because [they offer the path of least resistance](https://gardening.meta.stackexchange.com/a/218).